# woocommerce single product not working remove_action

Tags: php, wordpress

Guy's I have a simple problem but don't know how to solve it. I'm trying to modify woocommerce single product theme. I created a child-theme and in the `function.php` add code

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );`

that to remove price from a theme, but for me, it not worked.

all code function.php :

```
<?php

function aloshop_child_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'aloshop';

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'aloshop-child',
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
array( $parent_style )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'aloshop_child_enqueue_styles' );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

Can anybody give me advice what did I do wrong.

Comment: any recommendations??

Comment: *but for me, it not worked.* -- you need to clarify what happened here.

Comment: I think that I have to add some files to my child theme, but I don' know which